# How to make a field readonly in lightning record page?

Tags: custom-field, field-level-security, lightning-record-page

I have a field in field section in a lightning record page. I have set that field Read-Only in UI behaviour. But in UI, it is still editable.

[image]

Could Someone help me with this?

Comment: Does your user have [Edit Read Only Fields](https://help.salesforce.com/s/articleView?id=000383135&type=1) permission?

Comment: Remember that this option can come from the profile or any assigned perm set or perm set group.

Comment: are you using system admin profile to test this out? If you are using the Standard Salesforce Admin profile, you have the privilege to edit read only fields and save, unless you turn it off.

Comment: @prem22 Yes i am using Sys Admin profile with edit read only fields selected. Thanks

Comment: @PhilW yes for my profile Edit Read Only Fields are enabled.Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Any user with a profile or permission set assignment that includes the "[Edit Read Only Fields](https://help.salesforce.com/s/articleView?id=000383135&type=1)" system permission will see such fields as editable even when the page layout or dynamic form indicates the field should be read-only.